# In mysql it's not showing count value 0

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(cm.CUSTOMER_ID)>0,COUNT(cm.CUSTOMER_ID),0) COUNT
FROM  customer_master cm
JOIN customer_issue_details ci USING (customer_id)
WHERE ci.ACTUAL_DATE_RETURN < ci.RETURN_DATE
   AND CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE 'r%'
GROUP BY cm.`CUSTOMER_ID`;
```

When no such record is found it is not showing 0 under count but showing only alias count. How to get 0 under count.I have used ifnull,ifisnull also but of no use.
Please can any one tell why this is not working and how to get that 0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN. And every condition for any `ci` column must be in the ON clause (otherwise the LEFT JOIN will be converted to INNER JOIN). And you have to count `ci.CUSTOMER_ID` not `cm.CUSTOMER_ID`.

```sql
SELECT cm.CUSTOMER_ID, COUNT(ci.CUSTOMER_ID) COUNT
FROM  customer_master cm
LEFT JOIN customer_issue_details ci
  ON  ci.customer_id = cm.CUSTOMER_ID
  AND ci.ACTUAL_DATE_RETURN < ci.RETURN_DATE
WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE 'r%'
GROUP BY cm.`CUSTOMER_ID`;
```

The INNER JOIN (JOIN is an alias for INNER JOIN) will filter out any row from `cm` table if no row from the `ci` table has been found matching the JOIN condition (It doesn't matter if you use `USING` or `ON`). The LEFT JOIN will return at least one row from `cm` table, but if no row from `ci` table has been found matching the JOIN condition, all columns from `ci` table will be NULL.

Example:

```sql
cm:
| customer_id |
|-------------|
|           1 |
|           2 |
|           3 |

ci:

| customer_id | 
|-------------|
|           1 |
|           1 |
|           2 |
```

INNER JOIN:

```sql
SELECT cm.customer_id as `cm.customer_id`, ci.customer_id as `ci.customer_id`
FROM cm
JOIN ci 
  ON ci.customer_id = cm.customer_id;

| customer_id | customer_id |
|-------------|-------------|
|           1 |           1 |
|           1 |           1 |
|           2 |           2 |
```

LEFT JOIN:

```sql
SELECT cm.customer_id, ci.customer_id
FROM cm
LEFT JOIN ci 
  ON ci.customer_id = cm.customer_id;

| customer_id | customer_id |
|-------------|-------------|
|           1 |           1 |
|           1 |           1 |
|           2 |           2 |
|           3 |      (null) |
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4eb90/7)

With `GROUP BY cm.customer_id` and `COUNT(ci.customer_id)` you can count the number of found rows each `cm.customer_id`.

```sql
SELECT cm.customer_id, COUNT(ci.customer_id)
FROM cm
LEFT JOIN ci 
  ON ci.customer_id = cm.customer_id
GROUP BY cm.customer_id

| customer_id | COUNT(ci.customer_id) |
|-------------|-----------------------|
|           1 |                     2 |
|           2 |                     1 |
|           3 |                     0 |
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4eb90/8)

It returns `0` for `cm.customer_id = 3` because COUNT counts only values that are NOT NULL.

If you use `COUNT(cm.customer_id)` instead you will get `1` for `cm.customer_id = 3` because it's not NULL. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4eb90/9)

Now if you have any condition for a column in `ci` table (like `ci.customer_id < 2`) and you put it in the WHERE clause, all rows that do not match that condition will be filtered out.

```sql
SELECT cm.customer_id, ci.customer_id
FROM cm
LEFT JOIN ci 
  ON  ci.customer_id = cm.customer_id
WHERE ci.customer_id < 2

| customer_id | customer_id |
|-------------|-------------|
|           1 |           1 |
|           1 |           1 |
```

But moving that condition into the LEFT JOIN ON clause you keep at least one row for each `cm.customer_id`, because this is how LEFT JOIN works.

```sql
SELECT cm.customer_id, ci.customer_id
FROM cm
LEFT JOIN ci 
  ON  ci.customer_id = cm.customer_id
  AND ci.customer_id < 2

| customer_id | customer_id |
|-------------|-------------|
|           1 |           1 |
|           1 |           1 |
|           2 |      (null) |
|           3 |      (null) |
```

Now `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT cm.customer_id, COUNT(ci.customer_id)
FROM cm
LEFT JOIN ci 
  ON  ci.customer_id = cm.customer_id
  AND ci.customer_id < 2
GROUP BY cm.customer_id;

| customer_id | COUNT(ci.customer_id) |
|-------------|-----------------------|
|           1 |                     2 |
|           2 |                     0 |
|           3 |                     0 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4eb90/15)

Comment: Thanx,it worked.....i was writing USING Clause instead of ON clause that'why o/p was not coming..........Please tell why you have written (AND ci.ACTUAL_DATE_RETURN < ci.RETURN_DATE) just after ON clause.B/c when i am writing above statement in WHERE clause i am not getting o/p as 0??

Comment: @Stone, i hope the update will answer all your questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, try using grouping not by the `cm.CUSTOMER_ID` but by the `ci.CUSTOMER_ID`. Also, I think you need a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT COUNT(ci.CUSTOMER_ID)
FROM customer_master cm
LEFT JOIN customer_issue_details ci USING (customer_id)
WHERE ci.ACTUAL_DATE_RETURN < ci.RETURN_DATE
   AND CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE 'r%'
GROUP BY ci.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Here is SQL Fiddle simplified without `ACTUAL_DATE_RETURN` and without `RETURN_DATE`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cc64/2/0

**UPDATE 1**

> In ur fiddle if u change '%r' to '%a' it's not even showing output table but it should have given 0 under ur table name

This is how SQL works. Since there is no customer with name matching that expression, you get no result rows. You need to check for empty results set in your application.

Comment: @Stone: See the SQL fiddle.

Comment: @wix...thanks bro...in my sqlYog it's giving output for for any count>0 but not for count =0.....In ur fiddle if u change '%r' to '%a' it's not even showing  output table but it should have given 0 under ur table name

Comment: @Stone: I do not understand what you are saying above. Please elaborate.

Comment: @wix ...suppose if u give in ur sql fiddle  '%a' instead of '%r' so no condition is fulfilled...o/p should be like this -
COUNT(ci.CUSTOMER_ID)
0
but it not showing this o/p structure

Comment: @Stone: No, you are failing to understand how SQL works. What you say above is not possible.

Comment: @ wix i just want to know  my 1st query is not working

Comment: i just want to know my why my 1st query is not working to give count=0